# Importing huge SAS database to Rstudio

Tags: r, sas

I have a huge dataset in SAS (about 14 gb) that I am trying to import to R-studio for some analysis. However, nothing is working for importation. I tried 'haven', 'sas7bdat', 'foreign' but nothing. I converted the file to csv (became about 7gb) and tried read.csv, fread..but nothing again.
R-studio takes a huge time to process the file and at teh end says that it doesn't work. (something about not being able to allocate space for a vector of x size in mg about 60mg depending on the method used).

Does anyone have any ideas about how to solve this situation ?

Comment: R processes data in memory - do you have enough RAM to import and process a 7GB file? You would need at least 10GB if not closer to 21GB to allow other processes and any analysis to happen. So traditional R coding won't work most likely here.

Comment: https://inbo.github.io/tutorials/tutorials/r_large_data_files_handling/

Comment: @Reeza Thank you. I have 16 GB and I am still struggling. Do you think there is a way to work around this problem ? Or should I just learn SAS altogether ?

Comment: Whether or not to change languages is a bigger discussion than just this I would assume? Why did you pick R in the first place? Do you have access to SAS, otherwise a paid license is expensive and the free version doesn't work with files this large either.

Comment: @Reeza R is a program I am somewhat comfortable with. I got extremely little exposure to SAS. I do have access to the version with a paid licencse.

Comment: Maybe save the csv file to a [`disk.frame`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/disk.frame/index.html). Or use a DBMS.

Comment: Second the notion for a DBMS. However, `disk.frame` does allow reading large CSVs [by chunks](https://diskframe.com/articles/ingesting-data.html#ingesting-csv-files-chunk-wise), mitigating the "file is too big" problem).

Comment: This size of data is not intended to be managed on a desktop. I included some links on how you can process the files using R with various options but depending on what you're doing you may still run out of space. If you don't have access to a bigger machine or server installation I would then recommend you move to SAS but it will be a learning curve for sure. Or if you only need a portion of the data, split it in SAS then do the rest of the work in R.

Comment: @Reeza csv to sqlite option seems good. You can also look to [duckdb](https://duckdb.org) (MonetDBLite before). SAS is an easier environment for big files with sas7bdat on disk. But you can mimick this with an embedded database (sqlite, duckdb) and then do your data transformations with sql query like with proc sql operations. To load your csv into SQL Database there are severals options (load your big file in multiple parts (reader::read_csv( n_max = .., skip = ..) or see reeza [option](https://inbo.github.io/inborutils/reference/csv_to_sqlite.html)) .